# Apple Mach-O Linker Error IOS

Tags: objective-c

When i tried to build and run my project im getting this error.I tried may steps like clean and run, check with workspace.project but still im getting the error.No further details were in the error message. "Linker command failed with exit code 1(use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Use ⌘4 to have a look in Xcode's "Issue Navigator" for any clues. There's not much to go on in your question.

Comment: I can't find any solution

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reasons for this problem, sadly with such little knowledge of your project I can only suggest some fixes

1. Check for any caution messages and try to fix them
2. This can also be caused by using #import to import an .m file, if you are using this then remove it.
3. Sometimes this can be caused by frameworks and libraries, If you are using an external or custom framework, you probably need to add it to the "Frameworks" folder inside the application.

Hope this helped but if it didn't I might need some more info on your project.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Project file -> Build Phases** and check if there ara any red icons (specially for **Compile Sources** or **Copy Bundle Resources**)

Comment: if it is just remove it and re-add